# Android Heap memory allocation mechanism

Tags: android, memory, allocation

I would like to know how does the heap memory allocation happen on Android phones (OS).
what happens when I try to allocate an object of a few MB's (2-5 mb) and what happens when I try to allocate a huge memory (around 17-20 mb)...how and when is memory allocation successful?
I have seen some cases when there is enough heap available but still it would result with OOM. I would like to know more on this...any pointers on this would be helpful...

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Girish

Comment: Android is a Linux kernel, and the syscall to get memory is `mmap` so see http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html

Comment: Hi Basile,   Thanks for this.
Yes this is correct, but what happens when the memory allocation is requested? are there any algorithm or mechanism for allocation? 
As I told when and why will the memory allocation fail - even there is enough heap? I understand there will be some allocation mechanism, I would like to know about that

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you sure to understand what syscalls are (from the application point of view, it is an elementary atomic operation).

Comment: Do you mean heap allocation inside the Dalvik virtual machine, or heap allocation inside a native binary executable or shared object???